# Make https request with HAProxy without explicitly mentioning certificates?

Tags: security, ssl, tunneling, haproxy

**Why?**

Some app started making annoying authentication verification that work with the region. Every time I travel, and I login from another country, I have to go through a very annoying process of verifying that it was ME who did login that takes at least 15 minutes per account + some times I have to regenerate things... very annoying. Even though I have 2 or some times 3 factor authentication. My opinion on that is not important, but I want to circumvent this because I don't have time to constantly appease them and their weird security practices. HAProxy seems to be a way to do this.

**My plan:**

1. Make an SSL/TLS request of the service to a server of mine with my own domain name
2. Receive the latter request in my server, decrypt it with my own SSL private key in my server
3. Take that request in plaintext, encrypt it in a new SSL/TLS session, and send it to the server to get the service.

This can be done in HAProxy easily. You define a frontend to receive the request, and a backend to create the request again. BUT...

**The problem:**

[I must mention the certificate to verify the service server](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/tls/#define-server-settings). Usually browsers and other programs use the system's certificates to find whether the call to any website is legitimate in a TLS session.

**My question is:** Is there a way to make HAProxy just depend on system certificates without me having to add/mention the certificate manually/explicitly?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question? https://serverfault.com/a/828180

Comment: @jcaron This solves the problem. Thanks a lot!